# Proof that $f \mu$ is a measure for $f \in (m \Sigma)^+$ (from Williams: Probability with Martingales)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

[Williams][1] defines for $f \in (m \Sigma)^+$ and $A \in \Sigma$:
$$ (f \mu) (A) := \mu (f I_A)$$
where $\mu$ is a measure and $I_A$ is the indicator function for $A$.

He states that the proof that $(f \mu)$ is a trivial consequence of the monotone-convergence theorem (MON) combined with the following linearity property: for $a, b \in \mathbb R^+$ and $f,g \in (m \Sigma)^+$ we have $ \mu(a f + b g) = a \mu(f) + b \mu(g)$.

I can prove it for finite unions, but do not know how to apply the monotone convergence theorem for an infinite union.

This is my approach:
To show that $f \mu$ is indeed subadditive, let $(F_i)_i \in \Sigma$ be a finite sequence of disjoint sets. For $n \in \mathbb N$, we have $$ (f \mu) (\cup_{i=1}^n F_i) = \mu (f I_{\cup_{i=1}^n F_i}) \\ =\mu ( \sum_{i=1}^n f I_{F_i}) \\  = \sum_{i=1}^n\mu ( f I_{F_i}) \\ = \sum_{i=1}^n (f \mu)(F_i)$$

where the first step is by definition of $(f \mu)$, the second since the $F_i$ are disjoint, the third by the linearity property, and the last by definition of $(f \mu)$ again. Where can I apply MON now? It somehow needs to be after using linearity, since we have the linearity property only for finite sums (strictly speaken only for 2 but that can be easily extended to any number $n$ of summands).

[1]: Williams, D. (1991). Probability with Martingales. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9780511813658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (f \mu)(F_n) &= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (f \mu)(F_n) \\
&= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu \left( \sum_{n = 1}^N f I_{F_n}\right) \\
&= \mu \left( \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N f I_{F_n}\right) \tag{Monotone Convergence} \\
&= \mu (f \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} I_{\bigcup_{n=1}^N F_n}) \\
&= \mu (f I_{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n}) \\
&= (f \mu)\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n\right).
\end{align}
This depends on $f$ being non-negative, but can be easily extended to general $f$ by using the dominated convergence theorem instead of monotone convergence.